# Remove a node from XML with namespace and generate new XML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I am trying to filter the results of an XML feed generated for Facebook. Currently, the feed looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title><![CDATA[Title]]></title>
    <link><![CDATA[https:/path/]]></link>
    <description>WooCommerce Product List RSS feed</description>
    <metadata>
      <ref_application_id>451257172939091</ref_application_id>
    </metadata>
    <item>
      <g:id>anID</g:id>
      <g:inventory>5</g:inventory>
      <g:description><![CDATA[Some Text]]></g:description>
      <g:condition>new</g:condition>
      <g:mpn>sku</g:mpn>
      <g:title>Product Title</g:title>
      <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
      <g:price>185.00 EUR</g:price>
      <g:brand><![CDATA[BRAND1]]></g:brand>
    </item>
    <item>
      <g:id>anID</g:id>
      <g:inventory>5</g:inventory>
      <g:description><![CDATA[Some Text]]></g:description>
      <g:condition>new</g:condition>
      <g:mpn>sku</g:mpn>
      <g:title>Product Title</g:title>
      <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
      <g:price>185.00 EUR</g:price>
      <g:brand><![CDATA[BRAND2]]></g:brand>
    </item>
    <item>
      <g:id>anID</g:id>
      <g:inventory>5</g:inventory>
      <g:description><![CDATA[Some Text]]></g:description>
      <g:condition>new</g:condition>
      <g:mpn>sku</g:mpn>
      <g:title>Product Title</g:title>
      <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
      <g:price>185.00 EUR</g:price>
      <g:brand><![CDATA[BRAND2]]></g:brand>
    </item>
............
```

I need to remove some nodes based on the brand value. My code currently looks like this:

```
$xmlstr = get_xml_from_url('urlToXMLFeed/xml/testfeed1.xml');
$xmlobj = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);
$xmlobj->registerXPathNamespace("g", "http://base.google.com/ns/1.0");
$i = 0;

foreach($xmlobj->channel->item as $item)
{
    $namespaces = $item->getNameSpaces(true);
    // echo $namespaces;
    $gbrand = $item->children($namespaces['g']);
    $finalBrand = $gbrand->brand;
    if(strcmp($finalBrand,"BRAND2") == 0)
    {
        
        unset($item);
    }
    $i ++;
}

//Format XML to save indented tree rather than one line and save
$dom = new DOMDocument('1.0');
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($xmlobj->asXML());
$dom->save('fileName.xml');
```

The newly generated XML still has the nodes with the BRAND2. Also, tried using this to remove the node

```
unset($xmlobj->channel->item->{$i});
```

But the second approach only removes the first occurrence of BRAND2.

Also tried the following:

```
$domElemsToRemove = array();
.......
    if(strcmp($finalBrand,"BRAND2") == 0)
    {
        $domElemsToRemove[] = $item;
    }
}
....
foreach( $domElemsToRemove as $domElement ){
    $xmlobj->channel->removeChild($domElement);
}
```

But still the same result

Comment: It is much better and easier to use XSLT transformation for such tasks.

Answer (score 1):

I found a possible solution for my case. According to a PHP comment [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domnode.removechild.php#90292), we can not directly remove nodes, as it was my first approach because it will break the loop. Thus, we have to create a queue with the nodes we wish to remove. Then, based on the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9019163/5240156) the solution is this

```
foreach( $domElemsToRemove as $domElement )
{
    $dom = dom_import_simplexml($domElement);
    $dom->parentNode->removeChild($dom);
}
```

That removes all the nodes from the XML object properly!

Comment: Please don't miss the XSLT based solution.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky I will definitely try that later on. It's something new to me! But, thank you very much for your response!

Comment: This single line `<xsl:template match="item[g:brand='BRAND2']"/>` does the whole magic.

Answer (score 1):

You're already pretty close. With PHP SimpleXML:

```php
$xmlobj = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlstr);

foreach ($xmlobj->xpath('//item[g:brand="BRAND2"]') as $item) {
    unset($item[0]);
}

# output ...
```

See it running online: https://3v4l.org/nWOrY

This works already because:

1. `unset($item)` only unsets the variable. Using the [*SimpleXMLElement self-reference*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3153704/367456) `$item[0]` removes the element from the XML document with *`unset`*.
2. Traversal by `foreach ($xmlobj->channel->item as $item)` invalidates if `unset($item[0])` is called within the foreach-body (PHP Fatal error: *Uncaught Error: SimpleXMLElement is not properly initialized*). Foreach-ing over an ***array*** of **SimpleXMLElement**s is immune. `$xmlobj->xpath()` returns such an array already.

   Such an array could be created as well with `iterator_to_array($xmlobj->channel->item, false)` (second parameter `false` with SimpleXML!) if you do not want to use `SimpleXMLElement::xpath()` function.
3. XPath in SimpleXML has the XPath Namespaces already registered ("`g`" for "`http://base.google.com/ns/1.0`" as it is defined in the XML document element).
4. XPath itself is powerful in querying the document for elements (or attributes).

Some references:

Compare with the answer [*Remove a child with a specific attribute, in SimpleXML for PHP* (2008 by Stefan Gehrig)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/262556/367456) which is nearly identical to your scenario, different only in the decision on attribute - not element - content and don't miss the *"By the way: selecting specific nodes is much more simple when you use XPath"* part at the end.

Then compare [with my 2013 answer there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16062633/367456) that shows the *SimpleXMLElement self-reference* (with `unset`). It is a concept that dates back to earlier contributions on Stackoverflow, for example in
[*Remove multiple empty nodes with SimpleXML* (2012 by Beshoy Girgis)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9048668/367456) and there should be a couple more.

Perhaps [*Kamil Szot*](https://stackoverflow.com/users/166921/kamil-szot) [coined the term ***SimpleXMLElement self-reference*** back in June 2010 with *How can I set text value of SimpleXmlElement without using its parent?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3153704/367456)

And some closing comment:

I write this as well because as far as SimpleXML is of concern, DOMNodeList or importing into DOM (`dom_import_simplexml()`) should not be necessary for element deletion. It's more about using an array if you want to delete a list of elements as the traversal (perhaps *similar* to *DOMNodeList* behaviour) as just foreach-ing breaks with the first deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution based on XSLT.

It removes all `<item>` elements with the `g:brand='BRAND2'`.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
    <channel>
        <title><![CDATA[Title]]></title>
        <link><![CDATA[https:/path/]]></link>
        <description>WooCommerce Product List RSS feed</description>
        <metadata>
            <ref_application_id>451257172939091</ref_application_id>
        </metadata>
        <item>
            <g:id>anID</g:id>
            <g:inventory>5</g:inventory>
            <g:description><![CDATA[Some Text]]></g:description>
            <g:condition>new</g:condition>
            <g:mpn>sku</g:mpn>
            <g:title>Product Title</g:title>
            <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
            <g:price>185.00 EUR</g:price>
            <g:brand><![CDATA[BRAND1]]></g:brand>
        </item>
        <item>
            <g:id>anID</g:id>
            <g:inventory>5</g:inventory>
            <g:description><![CDATA[Some Text]]></g:description>
            <g:condition>new</g:condition>
            <g:mpn>sku</g:mpn>
            <g:title>Product Title</g:title>
            <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
            <g:price>185.00 EUR</g:price>
            <g:brand><![CDATA[BRAND2]]></g:brand>
        </item>
        <item>
            <g:id>anID</g:id>
            <g:inventory>5</g:inventory>
            <g:description><![CDATA[Some Text]]></g:description>
            <g:condition>new</g:condition>
            <g:mpn>sku</g:mpn>
            <g:title>Product Title</g:title>
            <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
            <g:price>185.00 EUR</g:price>
            <g:brand><![CDATA[BRAND2]]></g:brand>
        </item>
    </channel>
</rss>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" cdata-section-elements="title link g:description g:brand" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="no"/>
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item[g:brand='BRAND2']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output XML**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8' ?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
  <channel>
    <title><![CDATA[Title]]></title>
    <link><![CDATA[https:/path/]]></link>
    <description>WooCommerce Product List RSS feed</description>
    <metadata>
      <ref_application_id>451257172939091</ref_application_id>
    </metadata>
    <item>
      <g:id>anID</g:id>
      <g:inventory>5</g:inventory>
      <g:description><![CDATA[Some Text]]></g:description>
      <g:condition>new</g:condition>
      <g:mpn>sku</g:mpn>
      <g:title>Product Title</g:title>
      <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
      <g:price>185.00 EUR</g:price>
      <g:brand><![CDATA[BRAND1]]></g:brand>
    </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```